# Book for Mahabharata (English version)

Tags: mahabharata, translation-request

Can anyone tell a good book of Mahabharata in English version?

The one I know is The Mahabharata: Complete and Unabridged (10 volumes) by Bibek Debroy ([www.exoticindiaart.com](http://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/mahabharata-complete-and-unabridged-set-of-10-volumes-NAJ762/))

[image]

Are there any other versions available?

I know this is a meta question but don't have enough reputation to ask in meta.

Comment: Why don't you try this http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/maha/index.htm, author is kisari mohan ganguly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good English version translation is by Kisari Mohan Ganguli. It is complete scannable and full translation.

You can download it here.

http://www.holybooks.com/wp-content/uploads/MahabharataOfVyasa-EnglishTranslationByKMGanguli.pdf

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily call the Ganguli translation the best; the Debroy translation is often better.  But the Debroy translation is under copyright.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan oh! you are right... there cannot be best translation...english language can't match beauty of Sanskrit verses.... the best is just to understand directly from Sanskrit... so I edited answer and write 'A good translation"

Comment: Haha I'm not saying anything that profound.  Obviously some translations of a Sanskrit work will be better than other translations, so there will be a best translation.  I'm just saying that arguably the Debroy translation is the best.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some book recommendations by Shatavadhani Dr. R Ganesh from his YouTube video [*How do I get into the world of Mahabharata? Where do I start?*](https://youtu.be/z8G_ubZv8cg?t=101)

1. [Mahabharata by C. Rajagopalachari](https://tinyurl.com/shbdor6)
2. [Mahabharata by Kamala Subramaniam](https://tinyurl.com/v5exqsm)
3. [The Mahabharata by Dr. N.V.R. Krishnamacharya](http://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/mahabharata-NAK811/)

A couple of free online translations:

1. Kisari Mohan Ganguli's translation at [sacred-texts.com](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/maha/index.htm)

   - Unabridged, but this is from 1896 so uses archaic English ('thou art', 'thou hast' etc.)
2. [hinduscriptures.com](https://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/itihaas/mahabharat/text-with-translation/vol-i/chapter-01/topic-1)

   - Unabridged, verse by verse translation. Not sure who the author or publisher is - the website ingeniously removed all those details!

Comment: the links are not working

Comment: SE replaces amazon.com links with special referral links but this appears to be broken now. Fixed the links now. @Bijujose