# Who was at Fault for Draupadi Vastraharan – Duryodhan Or Yudhishthir?

Tags: mahabharata

How Yudhishtr had the right to bet a woman’s honour, dignity and character in front of devils like Duryodhan and Dushashan? If he really had the guts to do that, can you really blame Duryodhan for Draupadi’s infamous vastraharan?

Comment: Towards [end of Nala-Damayanti story](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03079.htm), we find Brihadaswa-rishi imparting the knowledge of "science of dice" to Yudhishtira. This suggests Yudhishtira wasn't a good player and had a gambling problem too. Duryodhana & Shakuni just cashed in on the problem. Now some people think there was no Draupadi-vastra-harana in first place but just Dushasana dragging her to the king's court which was no less an offence. Whose fault? Difficult to judge without knowing the true story.

Comment: Incorrect @sv I am told there are some dharmas a kshatriya has to observe.Among them,not turning down invitation to swayamvara, hunting&game of dice. More importantly,he was instructed by Krishna (after Rajasuya) that in order to expiate the sin of bloodshed during rajasuya (sisupala was killed.Since yudhishtara was the yajamana of the yaga,the sin goes to him even if he himself didn't kill), he treat everyone as he treats krishna,react to everyone as he reacts to krishna,offer as if offering to krishna & not deny just as he would not deny krishna. So he accepted the invite to dice.

Comment: @sv "some people think there was no Draupadi-vastra-harana" what?

Comment: Like Yudhishtir was already aware that what Duryodhan is planning to do!

Comment: @moonstar2001 I think that means that some people speculate that Draupadi Vastraharana is an interpolation. There are several mentions of Draupadi being dragged in the Sabha in MB but no mention of the disrobing.

Comment: I think the fault lies equally with both the Kurus and Pandavas. Kauravas tried to humiliate a woman and the Kuru elders just watched dumbly while Draupadi was harassed while Pandavas had the audacity to wager her when they had lost themselves.

Comment: @moonstar2001 re: Draupadi-vastra-harana, [see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbicJ.png). I wrote an answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14042/2995) about Krishna's non-involvement in the whole dice episode. "I am told there are some dharmas a kshatriya has to observe" - if that was true, Duryodhana thru Dhritarashtra would've invited Pandavas again for another game after the 13 year exile & so on for the rest of life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading  above comments and answer just my opinion is, i don't think only Kauravas were responsible for draupadi’s fate ,i think all the people who was presented in raj sabha are equally responsible.
Because,

Wasn’t it the mistake of Yudhishtir to bet Draupadi, his wife in the very first place? Well, if Yudhishtir considers Draupadi as an object and bets her in a game of dice, then Duryodhan being the winner of the game as well as the object don’t you think so had every right to do anything to the winning thing ?

Bhishma Pitama, Vidur and Guru Drona crying and almost begging in front of Duryodhan for leaving Draupadi alone.
I still don’t understand Why they did not request Yudhishtir to stop the game when the question of betting Draupadi was raised in a game of dice ?

Duryodhan was a adharmi so obvious he didn’t listen to them but Yudhishtir for them was a dharmi. Don’t you think they should have asked Yudhishtir to stop his nonsense of betting people in the game of dice?

Answer (score 1):

It's hardly a opinion based question, as critical editions removes Draupadi's disrobing events considering it to be a later addition.

Take a look at the two conversation's below from KMG :

Yudhistir admits that he tried to snatch the kingdom from Duryodhana :

> Yudhisthira to Bhima-"I sought to cast the dice desiring to snatch
>   from Dhritarashtra's son his_kingdom with the sovereignty. It was
>   therefore that, that cunning gambler--Suvala's son--played against me
>   on behalf of Suyodhana. Sakuni, a native of the hilly country, is
>   exceedingly_artful. Casting the dice in the presence of the assembly, unacquainted as I am with artifices of any kind, he
>   vanquished me artfully."

http://sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/...

Here Yudhisthira himself accepted that Sakuni defeated him artfully in dice. Yudhisthira called Sakuni artful (skilled) in dice. He also accepted that he was unacquainted with the artifices [unskilled] in dice and that's why he was defeated [vanquished].

View of Balarama about Yudhistir :

> "Yudhishthira, though not skilled in dice and though dissuaded by all
>   his friends, challenged the son of the king of Gandhara, an adept at
>   dice, to the match. There were then at that place thousands of
>   dice-players whom Yudhishthira could defeat in a match. Taking
>   however, no notice of any of them, he challenged Suvala's son of all
>   men to the game, and so he lost. And although the dice constantly went
>   against him, he would still have Sakuni alone for his opponent.
>   Competing with Sakuni in the play, he sustained a crushing defeat. For
>   this, no blame can attach to Sakuni"

So even the characters from Mahabharata couldn't decide correctly about  who's wrong in case of the dice game.

But as per the deal Kauravas should have given Pandavas their land, when they decided no to, we can say Kauravas were at fault .

Even if we consider Yudhistira was at fault for the dice game they paid for it in the 13-year exile, also we should remember war didn't occur for Draupadi, it broke loose only when Duryodhana refused to offer 5 villages to Pandavas, so the dice game incident doesn't change the outcome .

Comment: "as Critical editions removes Draupadi's disrobing events considering it to be a later addition" - not true, see [this translation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzEZz.png) of Bibek Debroy based on BORI CE of MB. CE goes only so far as saying it's not Krishna who saved Draupadi's modesty which is why I asked [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17240/2995). Now [this piece](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbicJ.png) from another book argues the disrobing didn't take place at all.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, whatever opinion we will give here that will be based on today's mentality/culture/thinking instead of Dwapar yuga's. Time changed a lot now, so our thoughts towards various incidents also changed. We sees world with different views than people used to see in Dwapar yuga. If you think any incident is wrong then it's just your thinking (based on today's teachings/observation) But people of Dwapar yuga might see same incident with different point of view than us. So our opinion will be kaliyuga's opinion which can't judge properly every deeds of Dwapar yuga because we don't know how they use to see world that time.

**Now lets come to the question**

Although I am not going to give my personal opinion (already told u why) BUT you should have known one thing that Yudhishtir was Dharmaraaj. He had full knowledge of Dharma. He knew the brief difference between good and bad.

In his lifespan no sin has done by his hand and proof of this can be seen in a story where Pandwas try to go heaven with their body But only Yudhishtir was able to reach heaven with his body, only because of one reason that he was sinless. More brief story I have read earlier in this site also but don't remember what was that post (where pandwas try to go heaven) else I wanted to attach link of that post but couldn't find it here right now (I will update when I will find it).

Yudhishtir did only one sin (which was necessary that time) in his life which was at Mahabharat war when he try to show fake death of Ashwathama to Draunacharya. And He got punishment for his that sin in Narka in form of maya (Illusion). No other sin has done by Yudhishtir, Hence it's proved that Draupadi's vastraharan's culprit was not Yudhishtir. Mahabharat story Itself gives the answer of that at the end.