# What events in mahabharata can be explained only if Krishna was God?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna

the killing of Bhishma, Drona, Karna and Duryodhana were just adharmic trickery - don't need a God to make them happen.

Making karna and the other Kauravas forget the Vasavi shakti that had been kept in reserve to kill Arjuna (Vyasa is a good story teller - he knew people won't believe it if karna was made to forgot it for 10 plus days and so has him quarrel with Bhishma and stay out for 10 days) until it was wasted on Ghatotkacha can only be done by a God.

Any others?

helping Draupadi when she was being stripped is considered an interpolation.

Comment: Krishna opens his mouth & universe is witnessed inside his mouth. ?

Comment: 'Krishna opens his mouth...' - I don't think it's part of Mahabharata.

Answer (score 9):

Here are a few of the many examples:

1. On the 12th day of the Mahabharata war, Narakasura's son Bhagadatta, who was fighting on the Kaurava side, launched the Vaishnavastra or weapon of Vishnu at Arjuna, but Krishna covered Arjuna and absorbed the weapon with his chest. Arjuna asked Krishna why he would break his promise not to fight. Krishna responded that it's because the Vaishnavastra is an absolutely invincible weapon, capable even of slaying Indra and other gods, as described in [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07027.htm) of the Drona Parva of the Mahabharata:

   > Listen, O Partha, to this secret and ancient history as it is, O sinless one! I have four forms, eternally engaged as I am in protecting the worlds. Dividing my own Self, I ordain the good of the worlds. One form of mine, staying on the earth, is engaged in the practice of ascetic austerities. Another beholdeth the good and the evil deeds in the world. My third form, coming into the world of men, is engaged in action. My fourth form lieth down in sleep for a thousand years. The form of mine which awaketh from sleep at the end of a thousand years, granteth, upon awakening, excellent boons to persons deserving of them. The earth, knowing (on one occasion) that that time had come, asked of me a boon for (her son) Naraka. Hear, O Partha, what that boon was. Possessed of the Vaishnava weapon, let my son become incapable of being slain by the gods and the Asuras. It behoveth thee to grant me that weapon. Hearing this prayer, I then gave, in days of old, **the supreme and infallible Vaishnava weapon** to the Earth's son. I said also at that time these words, 'O Earth, let this weapon be infallible for the protection of Naraka. None will be able to slay him. Protected by this weapon, thy son will always, in all the worlds, be invincible and crush all hostile hosts.' Saying, So be it! the intelligent goddess went away, her wishes fulfilled. And Naraka also became invincible and always scorched his foes. It was from Naraka, O Partha, that the ruler of the Pragjyotishas got this weapon of mine. **There is none, in all the world, O sire, including even Indra and Rudra, who is unslayable by this weapon.** It was for thy sake, therefore, that I baffled it, violating my promise.

   So the Vaishnavastra is capable of slaying all humans and all Devas, and yet Krishna withstood it.
2. Krishna saved Draupadi from being disrobed by making her dress grow endlessly, as described in [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02067.htm) of the Sabha Parva of the Mahabharata:

   > When the attire of Draupadi was being thus dragged, the thought of Hari, (And she herself cried aloud, saying), 'O Govinda, O thou who dwellest in Dwaraka, O Krishna, O thou who art fond of cow-herdesses (of Vrindavana). O Kesava, seest thou not that the Kauravas are humiliating me. O Lord, O husband of Lakshmi, O Lord of Vraja (Vrindavana), O destroyer of all afflictions, O Janarddana, rescue me who am sinking in the Kaurava Ocean. O Krishna, O Krishna, O thou great yogin, thou soul of the universe, Thou creator of all things, O Govinda, save me who am distressed,--who am losing my senses in the midst of the Kurus.' Thus did that afflicted lady resplendent still in her beauty, O king covering her face cried aloud, thinking of Krishna, of Hari, of the lord of the three worlds. Hearing the words of Draupadi, Krishna was deeply moved. And leaving his seat, the benevolent one from compassion, arrived there on foot. And while Yajnaseni was crying aloud to Krishna, also called Vishnu and Hari and Nara for protection, the illustrious Dharma, remaining unseen, covered her with excellent clothes of many hues. And, O monarch as the attire of Draupadi was being dragged, after one was taken off, another of the same kind, appeared covering her. And thus did it continue till many clothes were seen. And, O exalted on, owing to the protection of Dharma, hundreds upon hundreds of robes of many hues came off Draupadi's person. And there arose then a deep uproar of many many voices. And the kings present in that assembly beholding that most extraordinary of all sights in the world, began to applaud Draupadi and censure the son of Dhritarashtra.

   And this is definitely not an interpolation, for reasons I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17241/36).
3. When Draupadi had only a morsel of rice in her pot and she has to feed Durvasa and a bunch of other sages, Krishna ate that single morsel of rice and that is enough to satisfy him and thus the entire universe, leading the sages to feel full as well, as described in [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03261.htm) of the Vana Parva of the Mahabharata:

   > When Kesava, that ornament of the Yadu's race, had the vessel brought unto him,--with such persistence, he looked into it and saw a particle of rice and vegetable sticking at its rim. And swallowing it he said unto her, 'May it please the god Hari, the soul of the Universe, and may that god who partaketh at sacrifices, be satiated with this.' Then the long-armed Krishna, that soother of miseries, said unto Bhimasena, 'Do thou speedily invite the Munis to dinner. Then, O good king, the celebrated Bhimasena quickly went to invite all those Munis, Durvasa and others, who had gone to the nearest stream of transparent and cool water to perform their ablutions. Meanwhile, these ascetics, having plunged into the river, were rubbing their bodies and observing that they all felt their stomachs to be full. And coming out of the stream, they began to stare at one another. And turning towards Durvasa, all those ascetics observed, 'Having bade the king make our meals ready, we have come hither for a bath. But how, O regenerate Rishi, can we eat anything now, for our stomachs seem to be full to the throat. The repast hath been uselessly prepared for us. What is the best thing to be done now?' Durvasa replied, 'By spoiling the repast, we have done a great wrong to that royal sage, king Yudhishthira. Would not the Pandavas destroy us by looking down upon us with angry eyes? I know the royal sage Yudhishthira to be possessed of great ascetic power. Ye Brahmanas, I am afraid of men that are devoted to Hari. The high-souled Pandavas are all religious men, learned, war-like, diligent in ascetic austerities and religious observances, devoted to Vasudeva, and always observant of rules of good conduct. If provoked, they can consume us with their wrath as fire doth a bale of cotton. Therefore, ye disciples, do ye all run away quickly without seeing them (again)!" All those Brahmanas, thus advised by their ascetic preceptor, became greatly afraid of the Pandavas and fled away in all directions.... Hearing Kesava's words, the sons of Pritha, with Draupadi, became easy in mind. And cured of their fever (of anxiety), they said unto him, 'As persons drowning in the wide ocean safely reach the shore by means of a boat, so have we, by thy aid, O lord Govinda, escaped from this inextricable difficulty. Do thou now depart in peace, and may prosperity be thine.'
4. Krishna created darkness to fool Jayadratha into thinking the Sun had set, so Arjuna could fulfill his vow to kill him before sunset, as described in [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07142.htm) of the Drona Parva of the Mahabharata:

   > Then Krishna otherwise called Hari, possessed of ascetic powers, that lord of all ascetics, having taken recourse to Yoga, created that darkness. Thy warriors, O king, thinking the sun to have set were filled with delight at the prospect of Partha's laying down his life. Indeed, thy warriors, not seeing the sun, were filled with gladness. All of them stood, with heads thrown backwards. King Jayadratha also was in the same attitude. And while the ruler of the Sindhus was thus beholding the sun, Krishna, once more addressing Dhananjaya said these words, 'Behold, the heroic ruler of the Sindhus is now looking at the sun, casting off his fear of thee, O foremost one among the Bharatas! This is the hour, O mighty-armed one, for the slaughter of that wicked-souled wretch. Speedily cut off the head and make thy vow true.' ... Hearing these words (of Krishna), Dhananjaya, licking the corners of his mouth, quickly shot that arrow which he had taken up for Jayadratha's slaughter, that arrow, viz., whose touch resembled that of Indra's thunder, which was inspired with mantras and converted into a celestial weapon, which was capable of bearing any strain, and which had always been worshipped with incense and garlands. That shaft, sped from Gandiva, coursing swiftly, snatched Jayadratha's head away, like a hawk snatching away a smaller bird from the top of a tree.

Comment: More bad news, the Durvasa episode is also [excised from the Critical Edition of MBH](https://archive.org/stream/InterpolationsInTheMahabharata/INTERPOLATIONS%20In%20The%20Mahabharata#page/n5/mode/2up/search/durvasas) as it's absent in most manuscripts. Krishna using yoga or his Sudarshana Chakra to save Arjuna's day is [also contested](https://archive.org/stream/InterpolationsInTheMahabharata/INTERPOLATIONS%20In%20The%20Mahabharata#page/n5/mode/2up/search/sun).

Comment: @sv. This "critical edition" is as good as nonsense. They are trying to change ramayana and Mahabharata religious epics into their own atheistic peices.

Comment: @sv. You can find better "Sanskrit scholars" than bibek debroy in streets of South india, moreover this  "indologists scholars" are themselves nonsense, ramyana and Mahabharata are kept after Buddha, the language of both epics is pre paninian yet the "scholars" give them the timeline of 100 bc?

Comment: @sv. Furthermore the bal kanda and Uttara kanda which they gleefully claim to be interpolation are themselves written in pre paninian Sanskrit. They say whatever which disagrees with their atheistic speculation as interpolation.

Comment: @AnubhavJha What is the version of Mahabharata that you follow? The one at sacred-texts.com? I suggest stick to one (like the author of this post has done) and preach that one as the gospel. Finding out interpolations in scripture is a science in itself and has to be done in a secular way. It's not for the weak hearted. And certainly not for people with an agenda (theistic or atheistic).

Comment: @sv. "Science" lol such an over exploited word, sadly most of the "science" of indologists is based on their athestic/19th century racist british bias, nowadays you can sell any garbage belief in name of "science".