# English translation of Mahabharata

Tags: mahabharata

What would be a very good English translation of Mahabharata in prose which is complete and unabridged?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Book for Mahabharata (English version)](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12280/book-for-mahabharata-english-version) & [What are some online sources to get unabridged Hindu Scriptures or to learn Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15424/what-are-some-online-sources-to-get-unabridged-hindu-scriptures-or-to-learn-hind)